# Export .tif Images and .geojson from Google Earth Engine to Azure?

Tags: google-earth-engine, azure

Is it possible to export a .tif image/.geojson file from Google Earth Engine to Microsoft Azure?

Comment: No, not directly. You have to export it to Google Drive or Google Cloud Storage, then move it to Azure.